# Does notify immediately invokes the waiting thread?

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java code where notify is called on the waiting thread after a certain condition is met but the waiting thread doesn't start running immediately. What could be the reason?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Showing code is a lot better than describing it. Please [edit] your question to include your code, sample input and output, and the expected vs. actual behavior. This will help us answer your question better.

Comment: I'll update question with example.

Comment: *"but waiting thread doesn't start running immediately"*, because the JVM decides when to start it, no your call. Calling `notify` on it just tells the JVM this thread is supposed to start again.

Answer (score 0):

`wait` (as well as `notify`) requires synchronization monitor to be taken. If code which calls `notify` does not release it then `wait` will continue to "wait" until monitor is released

```
// wait thread
synchronized (syncObject) {
   syncObject.wait(); // to proceed to next line, 
                      // this thread must wait until notify is called 
                      // and then take ownership over syncObject
   // next line
}

...

// notify thread
synchronized (syncObject) {
   syncObject.wait();
   while (true) {}; // infinite loop, syncObject is never released, 
                    // wait thread will never gain ownership over syncObject 
                    // and will never wake up 
}
```